# Is is possible to lift a tkinter Toplevel above fullscreen applications (such as games)?

Tags: python, tkinter, overlay, toplevel

I have a `tkinter.Toplevel` that should be visible above all other applications.  Using the `.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)` method will only lift the window above all other windowed applications, but not an application in fullscreen mode.

If it is not possible within `tkinter`, are there any libraries that can lift a window above all other applications?

---Edit: Code added---

```py
import tkinter

class TransparentWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # Make the window transparent
        transparent = self.set_transparent_color(
            window = self.master,
            color = "yellow"
            )
        self.master["bg"] = transparent

        # Make the window fullscreen and non-resizable
        self.master.state(
            newstate = "zoomed"
            )
        self.master.resizable(
            width = False,
            height = False
            )

        # Test text label
        test_label = tkinter.Label(
            master = self.master,
            text = "Test Text"
            )
        test_label.place(
            relx = 0.9,
            rely = 0.9
            )

        self.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)

    def set_transparent_color(self, window, color):
        """
        Mark a sacraficial color as transparent for a window.
        """
        window.wm_attributes(
            "-transparentcolor",
            color
            )
        return color


# Create window
root_window = tkinter.Tk()
TransparentWindow(root_window)
root_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code? Using `toplevel.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)` works for me. Try calling `toplevel.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)` after `root.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  My code has been added.  Note that I am making the `toplevel` zoomed via the `.state()` method instead of the `.wm_attributes()` method.  However, I did try using `.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', True)` just as you suggested and this did not change the behavior.  I am fascinated that you got it to work...can you see what I am missing that would let this `toplevel` raise above a fulscreen application?

Comment: What OS are you using? For me (win 10) it works perfectly. The window with the label are above everything else including other full screen windows. What full screen window are you using to test it?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 as well.  I am unable to keep my `Toplevel` above a livestream fullscreen window, created via the Xbox Console Companion app.  If I have the stream in windowed fullscreen mode, the `Toplevel` is above it, but unfortunately not in "true" fullscreen mode.  I admit that I have not tested other fullscreen applications, so perhaps the issue lies with this app in particular.  However, I need the `Toplevel` to stay above this app in particular, hence my testing with it.

Comment: I have confirmed that this does not work other full screen applications as well, not just the Xbox Console Companion.

Comment: Do those programs run with the native resolution. I have a really old program that changes the resolution on my computer and everything disappears from my screen.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know they use the native resolution.  I have recently learned that some apps can be run in "borderless" mode (controlled from within the specific app's settings) which seems to make it full screen but allows the GUI to be above it.  This will be my workaround for now.